# What is C equivalent?

Tags: c, linux, assembly, 32-bit

How can I translate this bit of assembly to C code?

**Assembly:**

```
foo:
   dd 1
   dd 2
   dd 3
   dd baa - foo
  dw 5
  dw 6
  ; ....  
baa:
  db 00
  db 00
 ;...
```

**C**

```
struct foo
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int c;
  int d;
  short e;
  shot f; 
};

struct baa
{
  int a;
  int b;
};
```

and then:

```
foo f;
baa b;

f.a = 1;
f.b = 2;
f.c = 3;
f.d = ?? // how do I translate this?
f.e = 5;
f.f  = 6;

b.a = 0;
b.b = 0;
```

Comment: I'm thinking `f.d = sizeof(foo)`.

Comment: @FredLarson: `x - y` yields size of `y` if `y` is following `x`?

Comment: @Jack: It's calculating the difference between the two labels' addresses. If you choose to view these as structs in C, then the result would be the size of the first struct assuming that they're adjacent in memory.

Comment: @Michael: Thanks. Actually I already had tried that but it give a different result in the C version. The error should be from another source then. I did struct because it will be fit by fread()/fwrite() calls and not all member are of same type size, e.g., int (dd) and short(dw). What else approach would use instead of?

Comment: Do the structs contain more members than the ones you've shown? If so, there may be some padding inserted by the compiler to align some of the members. You could try adding a `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` to the structs (or whatever your compiler uses if you're not using gcc).

Comment: Yes, they have. Much more. I'm using on gcc-compatible #pragma pack(1). But what was wrong was the value of member(in this case, f.d). The sizeof both are equals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The intention here is (probably!) to calculate the size of the `foo` structure.

In 'bare' assembly (without any fancy tricks like structures), the only way to do this without manually counting is to determine difference between the addresses of the first and last byte of the structure, plus one. Or, in this case, the difference between the address of the first byte of the structure and the address of the first byte *past* the structure.

In C, you have the `sizeof` operator, which determines (at compile time) the size of an instance of a type. This captures the intention much better. In your case, you'd say

```
struct foo f;

// ...

f.d = sizeof(struct foo);
```

or alternatively,

```
struct foo f;

// ...

f.d = sizeof(f);
```

Comment: So, if I have two adjacents labels named `a,b,c,d`  so `x = a - d = sizeof(A) + sizeof(B) + sizeof(C) + sizeof(D) ` right?

Comment: If you mean `x = d - a`, then `x = sizeof(a) + sizeof(b) + sizeof(c)`. You're not "jumping over" `d` in this case, so you're also not adding `sizeof(d)`. If that's still confusing: think of a fence, where `a,b,c,d` are fence posts, and the `sizeof` terms are the boards between those posts.